# Book: Civilisation has limited time to progress from medieval to space travel

Tags: story-identification, books, spaceship, medieval

Here is a difficult one: I only read the blurb on the back, and didn't read it at the time. Now I wonder what it was... It must've been early 90's, late 80's.

It was something like: "The civilisation is on a medieval level and has to develop a space ship within a generation as an angry god ramscoops his way towards them."

I could've sworn it was called something like "King Arthur's space ship", but that seems to be something completely different.

Edit: I think this may have been from two different books. The cover for "King David's Spaceship" definitely looks like something I have seen before, though no "angry god" (i.e. highly advanced or even sublimed/ascended opponent). I'll get the other suggestion "A Fire Upon the Deep" as well to have a look.

Comment: [Minla's Flowers](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6315985-thousandth-night-minla-s-flowers) by Alistair Reynolds has a character named Merlin trying to raise a post-apocalyptic society back to space flight

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @Valorum that sorts of reminds me of the *Safehold* series :-)

Comment: @LSerni - Except that the plot in *Safehold* was about trying to resist the urge to innovate, not encouraging it

Comment: I'm not seeing any [obvious matches](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=King+Arthur&type=Fiction+Titles) other than this: [King Arthur's Spaceship](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/30303097-king-arthur-s-spaceship)

Comment: @Valorum ...not quite: Merlin Athrawes is trying to (safely) uplift a post-apocalyptic medioeval civilization, overcoming the stranglehold the Holy Church has on Safehold and their ban on innovations. (S)he's the source of Charis' innovations, and the stated goal (I think in *By Schisms Rent Asunder*? During the flight with Cayleb?) is indeed to get back to space.

Comment: I would have tried Vernor Vinge's "The Children of the Sky" which is about a civilisation trying to build space technology before the blight (which really is described as using ram scopes) arrives.  But that book is from 2012 and so is far too late.

Comment: @Valorum No, the objective is to overcome the high tech systems put in place to keep them from innovating.  Merlin Athrawes has basically the entire tech knowledge of a starfaring civilization, although his industrial plant is very, very limited.

Comment: Minla's Flowers is definitely too new, as is Children of the Sky. Though both sound good, so I may pick them up as well anyway. The most promising is "King David's Spaceship", I'll try to get a copy to verify.

Comment: Not a precise match, but Poul Anderson's [The High Crusade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_High_Crusade) covers most of the points.  In this story an alien spaceship lands in an English village in 1345 where a party of knights is preparing to go to the crusades.  They successfully capture the spaceship and when the aliens take them to their home planet instead of to France, conquer that also.  The differences being that they have to learn to use the advanced technology but don't need to develop it, and there is no angry god on the way.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Possibly [King David's Spaceship](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?25410)?

I disremember much of it, but the titular vehicle is a primitive Orion-style booster using conventional explosives instead of nuclear devices.

The driving motivation for building the ship was that if your civilization was spaceflight-capable, you joined the ?Galactic Empire? under better terms. As in, an equal partner, instead of getting colonized.

Comment: That sounds very promising, I'll try to get a copy before approving.

Comment: "if your civilization was spaceflight-capable, you joined the ?Galactic Empire? under better terms" If you like this plot idea, check out Brin's Uplift Universe for a fairly similar concept.

Answer (score 4):

'Ramscoop' makes me think of Vernor Vinge's '[A Fire Upon the Deep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Fire_Upon_the_Deep)' in which a medieval civilization of sentient dogs is the intended destination of an advanced intelligence travelling toward them. The other space travelling civilizations are racing the intelligence to the dog's planet and their ships are all described as having ramscoops on the front.

Comment: Yeah - the Blight could easily be understood as an angry god